# The meaning of strace timestamp

Tags: c++, linux

When use `strace -T -tt -o outputfile myprogram`, the out put is like

```
16:14:37.576804 write(1, "EFFEEFFFEFFGGEEFEEFECEEDB"..., 4096) = 4096 <0.000014>
16:14:37.577121 write(1, ",...,,,.\tDEDEEDEDEEBDEEFECECFBEE"..., 4096) = 4096 <0.000015>
16:14:37.577434 write(1, "66098\tT\t41\t....,.....,,,.,,,,..."..., 4096) = 4096 <0.000016>
```

Does the first column mean the start time of that system call, or the finish time? As given -T, the last column is given as "Show the time spent in system calls. This records the time difference between the beginning and the end of each system call." Why is it different from the time gap between two write calls? As the first two, `16:14:37.577121 - 16:14:37.576804=0.000317 > 0.000014`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to an experiment I just tried:

```
strace -t sleep 2
```

the timestamps are the times the syscall started. (It showed a `nanosleep` with a timestamp that matched the preceding syscall, not the following one that was timestamped 2 seconds later.)

I can't say for sure that there isn't some measurement inaccuracy in the times, but you can't expect the time spent in syscall to be exactly the same as the difference in timestamps - your process has to do some work in userspace between the syscalls.

Answer (score 2):

I've just investigate that, so I think maybe it's worthed to revive this thread heheh

Based on Git code (HEAD in d091f1a9e2), the code is as follows:

```cc
trace_syscall(struct tcb *tcp, unsigned int *sig)
{
        if (entering(tcp)) {
                int res = syscall_entering_decode(tcp); // print the -tt timestamp
                [...]
                syscall_entering_finish(tcp, res); // measure the first timestamp for -T
                return res;
        } else {
                struct timespec ts = {};
                int res = syscall_exiting_decode(tcp, &ts); // measure second timestamp for -T
                if (res != 0) {
                        res = syscall_exiting_trace(tcp, &ts, res); // calculate the delta for syscall duration
                }
                syscall_exiting_finish(tcp);
                return res;
        }
}
```

So, in summary, -t / -tt grabs the time before the syscall starts, and even before the -T measure the first timestamp (to calculate duration later).